# Loading two different types of data to a webpage with http.createServer's callback

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, http

I'm trying to load an HTML page along with two separate CSS files through http.createServer()'s callback. Here's the important part of the code so far:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var htmlData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.write(htmlData);
  res.end();
}).listen(port);
```

When I try to load this, it also tries to load the CSS files linked within the HTML file. I've tried both adding direct links within the header and adding a script within the HTML file to add the links to the header, but neither work. How can I do this without putting the content of the CSS files directly within  tags in the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the request path and giving it the same file each time.

You need to serve the right file based on the request.

For example: if you want to serve two files `index.html` and `style.css`:

```js
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/' || req.url === '/index.html') { // respond to both / and /index.html
    var htmlData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(htmlData);
    res.end();
  }
  else if (req.url === '/style.css') { // respond to /style.css
    var cssData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/public/style.css");
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' });
    res.write(cssData);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(port);
```